# flutter run fails due to no identity

Tags: ios, flutter

Flutter run fails with the error below. It seems that it cannot find the identity. I could not find where this identity is defined.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                           1,233ms
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           39.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Target debug_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Failed to codesign /Users/musimsek/Documents/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework/Flutter with identity -.


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by activating `Automatically manage signing` in Xcode.

[image]